# Ordinal sequence of entities in devForce

Tags: c#, .net, entities, datamodel, devforce

For my entitymodel i'm using devforce to create this.
The problem i now have is the sequence(ordinal) of the properties of each entity is not how they should be.

In  the XML version of the edmx file the properties are in the correct order but when i retrieve the dataproperties the order of the properties is different

fe : in xml of the edmx order is 1. PK, 2. name, 3. description
but in the list op dataproperties they come out as 1. PK, 2. description, 3. shortname

How can i fix this order in the dataproperties so they have the correct order (as they are in the xml of the edmx which reflected the order of the table in sql) ??

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code and model?

Answer (score 0):

What i need the sequence from the xml instead of the sequence from the class

[class on model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJ1p0.png)

[class in model's xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb3ha.png)

Comment: What is your use case - why do you care about the order of these properties?  The EDM Designer (which is Entity Framework, not DevForce) generated the XML in your storage model based on the physical table.  If you've since modified the table and want to keep your model in sync, why not just recreate the model?  If you don't want to do that, you can hand edit the XML; but again, why?

Comment: i need to order to show them in the same order in a datagrid. It's a huge model with modified navigation properties so i would mean a lot of work to redo that all

Comment: Options - 1) You can hand edit the entity in the conceptual model, then open in the EDMX designer and do a save to regen the code.   Or 2) not rely on auto-generated fields/columns in your datagrid.  Or 3) if your grid raises an AutoGeneratedColumns event, handle that to rearrange things to your liking.